# Silverlight generated client code does not use global:: for namespaces

Tags: silverlight, wcf, wcf-client

I generate a service client for a Silverlight to WCF service, and I want to use existing DataContracts. When the client code is generated it does not use `global::` for the namespace so I get an error (Namespace conflict) that some classes can not be found. How can it be fixed?